# SharePoint 2013 Installation package failed for KB3115174

Tags: 2013, cumulative-update

I am trying to install `KB3115174` (**June 2016 cumulative update for SharePoint 2013**) and for the second time now it runs for probably an hour or more, then fails with a simple popup saying

> "The installation of this package failed.".

Prior to attempting to run this update I successfully installed Service Pack 1.

Is there a place I can find a log or something that would indicate why or where it failed?

Even better if there were pointers on what to look for as to why it failed as well.

The installation progress meter doesn't indicate any detail, other than it appears to be going through the actual file update process.

Comment: It can also be a problem with the install media. Have you tried downloading the files again?

Comment: I can do that, although I've used the same installation files on two other servers.  Although, I did copy them to each so maybe there was a problem with the copy...thanks!

Comment: Check the size of installation media, make sure you copy the files locally and also right click on file > properties.. Make sure it is not blocked.

Answer (score 1):

To find a log or something that would indicate why or where it failed

> Open Central Administration > upgrade and migration > check the upgrade status.

Check upgrade status with failed and check its log file as shown below

[image]

Comment: Thanks! When I go to that page I don't actually have anything listed; no upgrade sessions or details to select. I browsed to that file system folder and do not see any Upgrade*.log files either.  I did reboot the server after the installation failed; maybe I'll try it again and check this status page after it (presumably) fails .

Comment: I hope to help you , I am also here if you need any enquiry :)

Comment: You will not get anything on this page until you run the config wizard or run the upgrade against databases

Comment: Peter is having trouble installing the binaries, not upgrading the databases

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are having trouble installing the binary part of the patch.

Remember, the patch is "installed" in 2 parts, the binary install, which you are doing, then the farm database upgrade, which is done using PSConfig/PSConfigUI.

M.Qassas's answer only applies to issues during the 2nd part of the install (the PSConfigpart). You will have not logs in those directories from the binary install.

**My Solution**

I've had your issue occur when installing the binary from a network share across a slow(ish, 100Mbps) connection. My solution was to copy the binary locally and then install it.

Also, any reason why you are not installing the July 2016 CU?

A great place to reference when looking at SharePoint CUs and upgrades is [stefan_gossner blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/07/12/july-2016-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/)

The middle to bottom of the post has many links to SharePoint patching debugging and such.

Comment: I did copy the files locally because I was afraid trying to install over the network might cause problems.  One possible worry I had was the amount of free space; the update is almost 4GB and I've got 7GB free which seems like it should be enough, but I didn't see anything indicating not having enough room. I'm doing the June update since I originally did this on other servers before the July patch was out :-).  I'll check that other link, thanks!

Comment: I bet that is the issue, the files is a compressed set of files that have to be extracted to temp directories before installation. This normally happens automatically but you don't have the space for it.